# emacs ess julia hangs on "using DataFrames"

Tags: emacs, julia, ess

I'm trying to follow a very simple example to get started with Julia using ESS.  But the very first command:

using DataFrames

results in emacs' spinning slash, nothing else happens, and the command prompt is not restored.  This is emacs 24.3.1 on *OS X 10.8.5*, *ess-20140304.2344* installed via emacs' package system.  In my init.el, I have

(require ess-site)

```
(setq inferior-julia-program-name
      "/Applications/Julia/Contents/Resources/julia/bin/julia-basic")
```

**Note**: `/Applications/Julia is a softlink to /Applications/Julia-0.2.1.app`

I tried the "using" command with the **Julia.app** terminal and it worked fine.
Tried it using `julia/bin/julia-basic` in an **iTerm2** session and it hung.  Tried `julia/bin/julia-readline` in an iTerm2 session and it hung.  Tried `julia/bin/julia` and it worked in iTerm2 but not in emacs, which is strange since that's just a link to julia-readline.  Tried putting `julia/bin` on emacs' exec-path.  Nothing seems to work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: It doesn't seem to be specific to ESS or emacs as you can reproduce it in ITerm2. The best place to ask is julia-dev list or their github bug list.

Comment: True, thanks.  Actually it turns out to be OS X goofiness - case-insensitive file system, as noted in [a thread on julia-users](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/julia-users/using$20module/julia-users/DYRPKtWDR1A/hR_Pqgu-IdkJ).  In case anybody else runs into this: since I was experimenting with "using DataFrames" and ess, I put my code in - what else? - dataframes.jl.  So "using DataFrames" loads (evals) my source file, which calls "using DataFrames" etc. ad inifinitum.  Seems a Julia bug to me, but renaming my file solves the problem.